# What does this learning curve show ? And how to handle non representativity of a sample?

Tags: machine-learning

[==> to see learning curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW64V.jpg)

I am trying a random forest regressor for a machine learning problem (price estimation of spatial points). I have a sample of spatial points in a city. The sample is not randomly drawn since there are very few observations downtown. And I want to estimate prices for all addresses in the city.

I have a good cross validation score (absolute mean squared error) an also a good test score after splitting the training set. But predictions are very bad.

**What could explain this results ?**

- I plotted the learning curve (link above) : cross validation score increases with number of instances (that sounds logical), training score remains high (should it decrease ?) ... *What do these learning curves show ? And in general how do we "read" learning curves ?*
- Moreover, I suppose that the sample is not representative. I tried to make the dataset for which I want predictions spatially similar to the training set by drawing whitout replacement according to proportions of observations in each district for the training set. But this didn't change the result. *How can I handle this non representativity ?*

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3):

There are a few common cases that pop up when looking at training and cross-validation scores:

- Overfitting: When your model has a very high training score but a poor cross-validation score. Generally this occurs when your model is too complex, allowing it to fit the training data exceedingly well but giving it poor generalization to the validation dataset.
- Underfitting: When neither the training nor the cross-validation scores are high. This occurs when your model is not complex enough.
- Ideal fit: When both the training and cross-validation scores are fairly high. You model not only learns to represent the training data, but it generalizes well to new data.

Here's a nice graphic from [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-generalization-in-machine-learning) showing how model complexity and error relate to the type a fit a model exhibits.
[image]

In the plot above, the errors for a given complexity are the errors found *at equilibrium*. In contrast, learning curves show how the score progresses throughout the entire training process. Generally you never want to see the score decreasing during training, as this usually means your model is diverging. But the difference between the training and validation scores as they move forward in time (towards equilibrium) indicates how well your model is fitting.

Notice that even when you have an ideal fit (middle of complexity axis) it is common to see a training score that's higher than the cross-validation score, since the model's parameters are updated using the training data. But since you're getting poor predictions, and since validation score is ~10% lower than training score (assuming the score is out of 1), I would guess that your model is overfitting and could benefit from less complexity.

To answer your second point, models will generalize better if the training data is a better representation of validation data. So when splitting the data into training and validation sets, I recommend finding a way to randomly segregate the data. For example, you could generate a list of all the points in the city, iterate of the list, and for each point draw from a uniform distribution to decide which dataset that point belongs to.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation of the balance between complexity and error.